# Convert px to mm with integer or fractional values

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, regex

I found code that transforms values in CSS by parsing them with a regular expression. It works just fine for whole values, but when I try to convert a fractional value like `10.15px` it ignores the number to the right of the decimal point and gives me something like this `10.6.613756613756614mm`.

Here is my code:

```
searchPX = new RegExp('(\\d+)px', 'g');
searchPXDec = new RegExp('(\d+\.\d+)px', 'g');

$('button').on('click', function() {
    var css = $('textarea').val();
    var css2 = $('textarea').val();
    var result;
    var result2;
    if ((result = searchPX.exec(css)) !== null) {
        var px = parseInt(result[1]);
        var mm = px / 3.78;
        css = css.replace(px + 'px', mm + 'mm');
        $('textarea').val(css);
    }
    else if((result = searchPX.exec(css)) == null) {
        result2 = searchPXDec.exec(css2);
        if(result2 !== null) {
            var pxdec = parseFloat(result2[1]);
            var mmdec = pxdec / 3.78;
            css2 = css2.replace(px + 'px', mm + 'mm');
            $('textarea').val(css2);
        }
    }
});
```

I try to match with two regular expressions, then use `parseInt` for whole values and `parseFloat` for fractional values, but it's not working.

Here is a live version of the code: http://jsfiddle.net/trtcN/575/

Comment: so why are you not just using one reg exp? or reverse the checks....

Comment: I just tried this `searchPX = new RegExp('(\\d+(\.\d+)?)px', 'g');` and it gives me the same result.

Comment: Are you sure that 3.78 px = 1mm? I would expect different values for different devices.

Comment: We are passing the values to a wkhtmltopdf renderer located in a website and the software is still in an experimental stage, so I am not focusing too much on cross-device dpi at the moment. Might as well do my research about it later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match integer values as well as fractional values with `[0-9.]+`. All you need is this regular expression:

```
var searchPX = new RegExp('([0-9.]+)px', 'g');
```

Another problem in your code is that you aren't using the global match correctly. Instead of executing the regular expression once with `if`, you should test it repeatedly with `while` until the matches are exhausted.

Demonstration:

```js
var searchPX = new RegExp('([0-9.]+)px', 'g');

$('button').on('click', function() {
    var css = $('textarea').val(),
        newCss = css.slice();
    var result;
    while ((result = searchPX.exec(css)) !== null) {
        var px = result[1];
        var mm = px / 3.78;
        newCss = newCss.replace(px + 'px', mm + 'mm');
    }
    $('textarea').val(newCss);
});
```

```css
textarea {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>Convert PX to MM!</button>

<textarea>
#content {
    height: 50px;
    height: 50.14159px;
    height: 50.0px;
}
</textarea>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! This solved my problem. I'll take note of all you pointed out.

Comment: I found a subtle bug: one should keep the extracted number as a string instead of doing `parseFloat`. That's because we don't want `'50.0'` to get parsed to `50`, or else the replacement operation won't work. I have revised the snippet accordingly.

Comment: I also noticed that. After this I created two more similar scripts to change em's to px's and px's to pt's, and the three of them had that issue with values like `'10.50'`, `'10.500'` and so on. Thanks!